# Debug application with many events

Tags: c#, events

I'm in C# with VS 2015. I'm trying to debug an application (not written by me) using many events. There is a lot of buttons, all sending events. The problem is that some events are sent by a dll, example :

```
void Setalarm(int ID)
{
    functionInDLL.sendAlarm(ID); //raise an alarmEvent (don't know the exact name)
}
```

I can't see the code in `functionInDLL`, so I don't know which event is sent.

Is it possible to break when an event is raise/catch ?

In that case, it want to have a break in all function called when the alarmEvent is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps remove the dll reference. Add breakpoints where you have errors. Add the dll reference back.

This will take you some time but it is probably the simplest way.

Comment: For the moment I don't have error, i'm trying to understand how the application works. This application use an object. This object is treat by different functions using events. I want to understand how the application works before fixing errors.

Comment: I understand. What i was saying is this. You remove the reference to the external dll. then when you build you will get some errors, everywhere the dll was used. you place breakpoints on all the errors. Then you add the dll back. The errors will disappear and the execution will break everywhere the external dll is used.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint on the `sendAlarm` method and then hit F11. This will try to step into the method, as you don't have the source, Visual Studio will step into the first code that does (i.e. your event handler).
Needless to say this will only work for events that have an event handler attached to it.

When you need to discover all events that are raised you need to add a handler for each one of them. There's no other way because an event without a handler won't be raised.

Comment: actually I don't have the sources, pressing F11 on the instruction is like a F10. There is no way to put a break in an object EventHandler containing all the EventHandler in application ? Or the there is no tools in VS to debug events ? This application is using a very number of events and if I had to add a break one by one I will miss some.

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to handle all events at once. To prevent  yourself from missing one, you could write some code using reflection to handle all events of an object.